# Problems with Text() (Scala Lift)

Tags: scala, lift

I have this snippet:

```
class WelcomeSnippet{

  def list (xhtml : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {
    object sessionUserType extends  SessionVar[String](null)
    Helpers.bind("entry", xhtml, "edit" -> SHtml.link("/provider",() => sessionUserType("provider"), Text("Edit")))
    }
}
```

I think its ok, but I keep getting this:

> Not found: value Text

I assume i should be importing something I'm not, but I can't find what it is for the life of me.

Here are my imports:

```
import _root_.scala.xml.NodeSeq
import _root_.net.liftweb.util._
import _root_.com.connector.model._
import Helpers._
import _root_.net.liftweb._
import _root_.net.liftweb.http._
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import _root_.scala.xml.Text
```